# How to properly include ATL into Embarcadero project

Tags: c++, c++builder, atl, c++builder-xe7

I've been given a legacy Visual C++ project that I need to compile in Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7, but I have a problem with building it. For now, I have a problem with ATL libraries, which are needed for some components of the project:

- I already copied all ATL files from `include/atl` to `windows/sdk/atl`
- the project requires `atlsafe.h`. I've installed Visual Studio 2013, which has these headers, but I do understand how to use them properly. In case I copy `atlsafe.h` to `windows/sdk/atl`, I start to receive lots of errors which are related to the outdated `atlbase.h`. Once I replace `atlbase.h`, I start to receive more errors (expectedly), and so on.

Generally, the question is, how do I properly configure my C++Builder project for ATL, and where do I obtain the correct version of the headers? For example, for the boost headers, the problem was solved very easy (build proper version and add path to headers to `-I` directive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Embarcadero dropped support for ATL in C++Builder XE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2BBuilder_Uses_DAX_for_ActiveX_and_COM), replacing ATL with the Delphi ActiveX framework (DAX). In order to use ATL in C++Builder projects in XE and later, you need to obtain ATL support files (headers and library binaries) from an earlier C++Builder version, you can't use the ones from Visual Studio.  If you don't have access to an older C++Builder version, then you will have to forget about ATL and migrate the project to DAX instead.